# Damaged screen. Any hope but replacing?

Tags: laptop, display, pixels

I just unboxed an Acer laptop, and this is the state of the screen:

[image]

Tech support suggested a couple of programs to try and revive the pixels.

It looks beyond software repair to me. Am I right?

Comment: "it looks beyond software repair to me. Am I right?" - Software cannot repair LCD problems like in your example.

Comment: You mentioned you unboxed it like this? Just return it as a DoA (dead on arrival) and get a replacement. Let them sort it out themselves. A good store will do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By looking at it, that's hardware -- the LCD panel is fractured.

You can confirm it's hardware by booting into the BIOS/UEFI, (and perhaps to a different OS, for thorough testing).  If the problem still exists in the BIOS, then there's no way it can be caused by software.

Since you "just unboxed" it, box it back up and take it back to where you got it, that unit is effectively DOA.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a software problem (actually graphic drivers), but I think that display is physically damaged.

I would just try to switch actual display resolution and if fragments stay at the same position than it isn't software issue.

Comment: There is absolutely no way the problem, illistrated by the screenshot in the question body, could be caused by software.

Comment: It could, conceivably be a dodgy cable.

Comment: It looks damaged better replacing it